# Xamarin Android target version

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am receiving the error message below when trying to release a Xamarin Android app on the Play Developer Console

> **Upload failed** 
>   Your app currently targets API level 26 and must target
>   at least API level 28 to ensure that it is built on the latest APIs
>   optimised for security and performance. Change your app's target API
>   level to at least 28. Find out how.

I have the following settings in VS for Mac

[image: id]

Also, all of the Xamarin.Android libraries that I am using are v28.0.0.3.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be an issue with your Android support libraries or the version. Can you ensure the below and try to publish it with a new version?

- Ensure the latest SDK (API level 28) is installed in your Android SDK Manager
- Ensure you have the latest Android Support libraries and Build tools installed.
- Set your Android Target version to API level 28 and Minimum Android version to something lesser than that.

Answer (score 0):

Following points you should note:

- When Google play talks about target `Android` version it is talking about the `Target Framework` in your `Android` Project Properties.
- The error message that you are getting has nothing to do with what version of support libraries that you have. But when you target the latest version you might want to have the support libraries of the same version.
- Adding all the SDK's that your Android app is going to support is recommended which means if you Min Android support version is 21 per se and you want to target the latest version then make sure that your Android SDK has all these sdks's so that there are no issues while parsing your APK in the desired version.
- I wouldn't recommend that your min Android version is set to version 9 because of the fact 90% of the devices do not have this version of SDK which means none of them will be able to install or use your APP. Which if you ask me should never be the case. Supporting the widest possible audience is always the best call.

After making the above changes your app should work fine. Feel free to get back to me if you have any questions or queries...